# Изменение ширины verticalHeader в tableWidget (Qt)

Tags: c++, qt

Суть задачи: необходимо "вытащить" значение ширины заголовков (verticalHeader) одной таблицы, реализованной через tableWidget, в которой ширина этого заголовка может изменяться в зависимости от введенных значений, и задать полученную ширину для ширины заголовков (verticalHeader) другой таблицы, также реализованной через tableWidget.

Как реализовать изменение ширины второй таблицы я разобрался:
ui->tableWidget_2->verticalHeader()->setFixedWidth('здесь задается int ширина'),
здесь искомое значение ширины подставляется в функцию setFixedWidth().

Как "вытащить" значение ширины verticalHeader из таблицы?

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с этой задачей.

Answer (score 1):

Метод [verticalHeader()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html#verticalHeader) возвращает объект типа [QHeaderView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html).

Чтобы получить размер используйте метод [int QHeaderView::sectionSize(int logicalIndex)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#sectionSize).

Думаю, примерно так:

```
QHeaderView* vHeader = ui->tableWidget_2->verticalHeader();

for (int i = 0; i < vHeader->count(); i++) {
    qDebug() << i << vHeader->sectionSize(i);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но такая реализация выдает в qDebug() значение высоты заголовков (verticalHeader), а мне требуется ширина.

Comment: В ответе есть ссылки и есть пример использования.Читайте и делайте что вам нужно.

Comment: Документацию Qt про QHeaderView читал. Метод int QHeaderView::sectionSize(int logicalIndex) позволяет получить ширину только для horizontalHeaders.

Comment: @Noulzz, понял.. QHeaderView.виджет запросите у него ширину -- `width()` или, я не проверял, но попробуйте `sectionSizeFromContents(0)`и у `QSize`, что придет в ответе, взять ширину